# Generate XSD schema from xml file in visual studio in just only one file

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010, xsd

I've been trying generate `xsd schema` from `xml` file in order to obtaining the classes (*applying the xsd tool*). In `visual studio` with my xml `open: main menu -> Xml -> Generate Schema` and visual studio generates the schema in several files: 
One main file referencing the other ones. After that I have to copy the others files content into the main file to apply the xsd tool and generate the classes I want.

My question is, it would be possible generate all in just only one file?

Answer (score 1):

Can you change the xml file so all types are in the same namespace, thereby forcing xsd to create a single-file schema? See [Why does XSD.EXE Create Two .XSD Files, and How to Use Them?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1084071/why-does-xsd-exe-create-two-xsd-files-and-how-to-use-them)

Comment: Instead of generate the code based on only one xsd i tried in the xsd tool specifying the all xsd files generated by visual studio and it worked. Thanks it was useful.

Comment: @Mirlo But you are still using multiple XSD files.

Answer (score 1):

Each namespace in your XML file is considered as a separate schema (XSD).

Consider consolidate your namespaces into one so you could enjoy 1 file generation.

In addition, as a good reference, look at this related good answer: [xsd.exe generates two files, how to join them into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9675289/xsd-exe-generates-two-files-how-to-join-them-into-one)